How to fix the error: Unable to find suitable setter or adder for property Text?
How can I fix the error?
Error text:

Unable to find suitable setter or adder for property Text of type
LiveChartsCore:LiveChartsCore.VisualElements.LabelVisual`2 for
argument
Avalonia.Markup.Xaml:Avalonia.Markup.Xaml.MarkupExtensions.CompiledBindingExtension,
available setter parameter lists are:System.String Line 46, position
62.

LineSmoothness.axaml
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="600" d:DesignHeight="200"
             x:Class="AvaloniaApplication1.Views.LineSmoothness"
             x:DataType="vms:ViewModelLineSmoothness"
             xmlns:lvc="using:LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView"
             xmlns:ve="using:LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.VisualElements"
             xmlns:lvca="using:LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.Avalonia"
             xmlns:lvcp="using:LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.Painting"
             xmlns:lvK="using:LiveChartsCore.Kernel"
             xmlns:vms="using:AvaloniaApplication1.ViewModels">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vms:ViewModelLineSmoothness/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Design.DataContext>
        <vms:ViewModelLineSmoothness/>
    </Design.DataContext>
    <lvca:CartesianChart Name="ChartLine">
        <lvca:CartesianChart.VisualElements>
            <ve:LabelVisual TextSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Start" Text="{Binding TextMarker}"/>
        </lvca:CartesianChart.VisualElements>
    </lvca:CartesianChart>

</UserControl>

ViewModelLineSmoothness.cs
   internal partial class ViewModelLineSmoothness : ObservableObject, IItemViewModel
   {
     public string TextMarker { get; set; }

     public ViewModelLineSmoothness()
     {
     }
   }


LabelVisual is not an AvaloniaObject and therefore Text is not an AvaloniaProperty.  For this reason, it cannot have bindings assigned to it. It also has two generic types.  You have to create that in code behind.
